# commutator is normal subgroup is G of class 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to prove that if a finite group $G$ is of nilpotency class $2$, that then $[x,G] := \{[x,g] = xgx^{-1}g^{-1} | g \in G \} $ is a normal subgroup of $G$, for an element $x$ in the group $G$.

I know that $[G,G] = G'$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, but I have difficulties because here the $x$ is fixed.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: when $G$ has class $2$, the commutator function is bilinear: i.e.  $[x,g_1][x,g_2] = [x,g_1g_2]$ and $[x,g^{-1}] = [x,g]^{-1}$.